# How to fix error: incompatible types when returning type 'struct {aka struct <anonymous>}

Tags: c, visual-studio, sorting, random, struct

I'm making a code that returns a struct with random values. I keep getting error: incompatible types when returning type 'student {aka struct }' but 'struct student *' was expected return s;

I've tried many things and have looked all over the internet, but i couldn't find a solution.

Any help would be Appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int method = 3; //if 0, organize by all. if 1, organize by grade. if 3, organize by speed.


char first[40];
char last[25];

char* genName();

struct student* genStudent();

typedef struct
{
    char name[60];
    int score;
    double time;
} student;

char firstNames[][15] =
{
{"John"},
{"Jim"},
{"Tim"},
{"Sam"},
{"Jack"},
{"Larry"},
{"Bob"},
{"Mack"},
{"Kyle"},
{"Tom"},
{"Joe"},
{"Dan"}
};

char lastNames[][25] =
{
{" Howards"},
{" Nyles"},
{" Jones"},
{" White"},
{" Myles"},
{" Simones"},
{" Smith"},
{" Johnson"},
{" Williams"},
{" Brown"},
{" Jackson"},
{" Martin"},
{" Davis"},
{" Thompson"},
{" Moore"},
{" Wick"},
};

int compare(const void*, const void*);

student s1 = {"Jim Howards", 89, 4.90};
student s2 = {"Tim Nyles", 76, 6.12};
student s3 = {"John Jones", 97, 7.56};
student s4 = {"Sam White", 50, 1.12};
student s5 = {"Jack Myles", 88, 3.90};

int main()
{

       student array[] = {s1, s2, s3, s4, s5};


qsort(array, (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])), sizeof(array[0]), compare);

if (method == 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])); i++)
    {
        printf("%d.%s, with a score of %d%%\n", i+1, array[i].name, array[i].score);
    }    
}
else
{
    if (method == 2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])); i++)
        {
        printf("%d.%s, with a time of %1.2f minutes\n", i+1, array[i].name, array[i].time);
        }    
    }
    else
    {
        if (method == 3)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])); i++)
            {
                printf("%d.%s, with a score of %d%%, and a time of %1.2f\n", i+1, array[i].name, array[i].score, array[i].time);
            }
        }
    }
}



char* hi = genName();
printf("%s", hi);

return 0;
}

int compare(const void * num1, const void * num2)
{
    student *st1 = (student *)num1;
    student *st2 = (student *)num2;
if (method == 1)
{
    if (st1->score < st2->score)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (st1->score == st2->score)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (st1->score > st2->score)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
else
{
    if (method == 2)
    {
        if (st1->time > st2->time)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (st1->time == st2->time)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (st1->time < st2->time)
        {
            return -1;
        }   
    } 
    else
{
    if (method == 3)
    {

        if (st1->score < st2->score)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        if (st1->score == st2->score)
        {
           if (st1->time > st2->time)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            if (st1->time == st2->time)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            if (st1->time < st2->time)
            {
                return -1;
            }  
        }
        if (st1->score > st2->score)
        {
            return -1;
        }   
    } 
}
}
}

char* genName()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int r = rand() % (sizeof(firstNames)/sizeof(firstNames[0]));
    strcpy(first, firstNames[r]);
    int v = rand() % (sizeof(lastNames)/sizeof(lastNames[0]));
    srand(time(0));
    strcpy(last, lastNames[v]);
    strcat(first, last);
    return first;
}

struct student* genStudent()
{
    student s;
    srand(time(0));
    int sScore = rand() % 101;
    srand(time(0));
    double sTime = (double)rand()/(10);
    char* sName = genName();
    strcpy(s.name, sName);
    s.score = sScore;
    s.time = sTime;
    return s;
}
```

Comment: The function `struct student* genStudent()` does not return a `struct`, but a *pointer* to a struct and so `student s; ... return s;` is incorrect. Moreover you must not return a pointer to a local variable anyway. So the choices are, either return the `struct` by removing the `*` from the function definition, or, allocate dynamic memory for the `struct` and return a *pointer* to that.

Comment: Please read [ask] and produce a [mre] with emphasis on minimal.

Comment: Also you have `typedef`ed `student` so you should be working with `student` and not `struct student`.

Comment: Actually, I can't see anywhere in your code where you call your `genStudent` function.

Comment: Another thing: the function `compare()` does not return a value from all control paths. Compiler warnings are your friend.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `genStudent()` function is declared/defined as returning a ***pointer to*** a `student` structure but it is actually returning a `student` ***object***. You can fix the code as follows:

```
student* genStudent()
{
    student *s = malloc(sizeof(student)); // Allocate memory for a new object
    srand(time(0));
    int sScore = rand() % 101;
    srand(time(0));
    double sTime = (double)rand()/(10);
    char* sName = genName();
    strcpy(s->name, sName); // Change the "." to "->" as s is now a pointer
    s->score = sScore;
    s->time = sTime;
    return s;
}
```

Of course, at some point later in your program, you should be sure to release the memory allocated using `free()`!

EDIT: OK, to resolve any confusion, where you have the definition of the `student` type and the pre-declaration of `genStudent`, you need to change your code:

```
struct student* genStudent();

typedef struct
{
    char name[60];
    int score;
    double time;
} student;
```

To this:

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[60];
    int score;
    double time;
} student;

student* genStudent();
```

Feel free ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: `struct student` is also incorrect, it has not been defined.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry, typed in my code too quickly (there were some other errors, too). Using `struct student` does compile, but with warnings.

Comment: MSVC gives an actual error: *genStudent uses undefined struct student*.

Comment: Well, with MSVC in Visual Studio 2019, adding the `struct` keyword (in the definition of `genStudent`) compiles with this bizarre warning: `warning C4133: 'return': incompatible types - from 'student *' to 'student *'`

Comment: @WeatherVane But I agree - the keyword should ***not*** be used when it has been declared with `typedef`!!

Comment: Yeah, it did end up running but i got the error:  warning: return from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     return s;

Comment: I removed the struct keyword but i got three more errors.                               warning: return from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     return s;                                                                                                            error: conflicting types for 'genStudent'                                                                 note: previous declaration of 'genStudent' was here
 student* genStudent();
 student* genStudent()

Comment: @TechnoTaco Remove the `struct` keyword from the earlier declaration, too! In fact, wherever you have a `student` variable, just define/declare as: `student myStudent` - you don't need the `struct` (it's already defined in the `typedef`).

Comment: I already got rid of all of the struct keywords. Its still giving me the errors

Comment: @TechnoTaco But you need to keep it after the `typedef` keyword! That's where you are telling the compiler that your variable type `student` is a struct.

Comment: @TechnoTaco Also, move your `student* genStudent();` declaration line so that it comes ***after*** the `typedef` - otherwise the compiler won't know what `student` is!

Comment: That was the problem. All of the errors are gone. Thank you for helping me with this.